# Android layout render without compiling

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to developing with Android, and the biggest new thing is the way the UI is rendered (relative to other views instead of absolute locations and sizes).  As a result, I've been experimenting a *lot* with layouts, and find myself changing 1 view or even just 1 property of a view, then having to recompile and launch it back into the emulator to see the result.  Is there a tool that quickly (or at least quicker) shows what a UI looks like give a layout xml file?

Comment: Aren't you using Eclipse? ADT for Eclipse has a visual editor. It's, well, "not perfect", but it's a good start for experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at http://www.droiddraw.org/ but it is not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse with [Android Development Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), when opening a layout file you get a preview of what looks like. Besides, ADT provides some nice features for developing and debugging in the Android platform.

Answer (score 1):

When you're in the XML view, simply click the "Layout" tab on the bottom, and you'll be taken to a visual representation of your layout:

[image: xml view]

Like so:

[image]

There are some limitations for sure (e.g. text shadowing, for one, will not be depicted in this view), but it's a good way to get a general idea of how your layout is working.

Answer (score 0):

Versions 2.x and higher of Android Studio render the XML in real-time in the Preview pane of the IDE and it even juxtaposes the XML and outline views side by side.